# How to handle state camera when minimize app in tablet?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a problem with Camera, I using media capture, when i minimize app and show agin => camera preview crash. I try restart preview in method Supending but it don't working. Please help me
Thanks for all

Comment: Hi @trongdeptrai99 does the following works, and do you have any updates?

Answer (score 0):

> I try restart preview in method Supending but it don't working.

The application [`Suspending`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.suspending) event will be triggered when app minimized, you need to stop preview but not restart preview and restart the preview in application [`Resuming`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.resuming) event. We also provide the complete [code sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CameraGetPreviewFrame/cs/MainPage.xaml.cs#L95) that could handle the app minimized and resumed.